# Tensorflow sequence mask without reducing dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a sample code to run:

```
import numpy a np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
tfe.enable_eager_execution()

x = np.random.randint(100,size=(4,4))
indexes =tf.sequence_mask([1,2,2,4],4)
"""
indexes = [
    [True,False,False,False],
    [True,True,False,False],
    [True,True,False,False],
    [True,True,True,True],
]
"""

y = tf.boolean_mask(x,indexes)
# y = array([43, 78, 68, 54, 46, 28, 15, 52,  3])
```

Now, I don't want this as the spatial information of the original tensor is lost and I want to keep the shape intact. How can do that in tensorflow since I work with RNN data so my tensor size is = `[batch_size, max_time, feature_length]` where I would slice it such that:

`indexes = tf.sequence_mask([x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_batch_size], max_time)`

but still want to keep the shape intact. If its not possible, is there a way to sequence mask on multiple tensors of such size while also concatenating them so that only the extracted sequence would remain and not the masked out paddings? Paddings could be applied on the end of the concatenation.

Comment: good question, I'm running into the exact same problem for `tf.boolean_mask()`. I think this is a limitation of the current implementation, and like certain other tensorflow library functions, both `sequence_mask()` and `boolean_mask()` could use an additional `keepdims=True` option.

Comment: @datwelk I have solved it, with a hacky solution. Would you like an answer or help with that?

Comment: I'd be interested to see it, perhaps you could post it below as an answer to your question? I saw your (closed) issue on the tensorflow github page, I have created a new one for boolean_mask and explicitly mentioned it is a feature request in order not to get redirected to Stackoverflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18238

Answer (score 0):

This may work-

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4],
             [5, 6, 7, 8],
             [9, 10, 11, 12],
             [13, 14, 15, 16]])

indexes = tf.sequence_mask([1, 2, 2, 4], 4)
y = tf.multiply(x, tf.cast(indexes, x.dtype))

-> y is [[ 1  0  0  0]
         [ 5  6  0  0]
         [ 9 10  0  0]
         [13 14 15 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/boolean_mask) might help you, though it will depend on how your result is used (I used 'j' below instead of 'x'):

```
>>>j = np.random.randint(100,size=(4,4))
>>>indexes =tf.sequence_mask([1,2,2,4],4)

>>>tf.ragged.boolean_mask(j, indexes)
<tf.RaggedTensor [[75], [11, 8], [20, 40], [24, 30, 75, 77]]>
```